# Python Error: AttributeError: __enter__ Here

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, virtualenv

```py
I = mpimg.imread(FACE_INPUT_PATH + picname)
I_np = np.array(I)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "pretrain_load_test.py", line 67, in <module>
        I = mpimg.imread(FACE_INPUT_PATH + picname)
    File "/home/avicky/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", 
        line 1417, in imread
            with Image.open(fname) as image:
    AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: Can you make your example complete i.e. can you show us your imports?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your libs, its seems like version conflicts

`pip install -U pillow`